# pass the selected drop box value id to the url of the next page

Tags: url

Im vey new to php. How to pass the selected drop box value to next page url? I have something like this:-

```
<script language="javascript">
    function showMe(str)
    {
    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = 'You have selected :'+str;
    }   
    </script>
    <select id="ccrseid" name="ccrseid" onchange="showMe(this.value);">
   <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Computer Science</option>
    <option value="2">Engineering</option>
    <option value="3">Business</option>
    <option value="4">Education and Training</option>

   </select>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
    </html>
<a href="#"onclick="document.location.href='timer.php?selectvalue='+document.getElementById('myDiv').value">Submit</a>
```

when i execute im getting "undefined" at the url .

```
http://localhost/timer.php?selectvalue=undefined
```

how do i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your question, there seems like there are two different outcomes you want to achieve; the first being that you want to pass the value of the `<select>` dropbox to the landing php page, while your example code suggests that you want to pass the `<select>` value with appending "You have selected :" to it. 
So basically - with the given information - there are two outcomes you want to achieve, the first being the final "GET" url being

```
http://localhost/timer.php?selectvalue=1
```

And the other with the "GET" url being

```
http://localhost/timer.php?selectvalue=You%20have%20selected%20:1
```

With the first outcome, using javascript is a bad way of approaching this, I suggest to you to use the standard html `<form>` tag to build your form and `<input>` instead of the `<a>` tag as a button

```
<form action="timer.php" method="get">
  <select id="ccrseid" name="selectvalue" onchange="showMe(this.value);">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Computer Science</option>
  <option value="2">Engineering</option>
  <option value="3">Business</option>
  <option value="4">Education and Training</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
<form>
```

With the second solution, that being to print the `<select>` value into a div and send that data to the landing page with a `<a>` tag, what you need to do is to to change the link on the last line

```
<a href="#"onclick="document.location.href='timer.php?electvalue='+document.getElementById('myDiv').value">Submit</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#"onclick="document.location.href='timer.php?electvalue='+document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML">Submit</a>
```

Comment: hi extramaster, thanks for the feedback. i,m clear now.i got it.

Answer (score 0):

Although possible with javascript I would recommend you do this with php. It ensures that your visitor does not need javascript enabled to be able to take advantage of the form too.

```
<form action="timer.php" method="post">
  <select id="ccrseid" name="selectvalue"">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Computer Science</option>
  <option value="2">Engineering</option>
  <option value="3">Business</option>
  <option value="4">Education and Training</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
<form>
```

Then at the top of your timer.php file...

```
if((int)$_POST['selectvalue']){
    header('Location:timer.php?selectvalue=' . (int)$_POST['selectvalue']);
    exit;
}
```

No need for javascript.